# How to get data from a relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a business model and subscriptions model. I load the data with the following:

```php
Business::with('subscriptions')->get()
```

I then created a method on my Business class as follows:

```php
public function check_for_subscription($type)
{
    if($this->subscriptions->isEmpty() === false)
    {
        foreach($this->subscriptions as $subscription)
        {
            dd($subscription);
            if($subscription->type == $type)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The dd shows me the following:

```
object(Subscription)#175 (17) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["table":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["business_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "614"
    ["starts_at"]=>
    NULL
    ["ends_at"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["business_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "614"
    ["starts_at"]=>
    NULL
    ["ends_at"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["softDelete":protected]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

If I try to do `$subscription->type` I get nothing. Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Here is the start of my business model

```php
class Business extends Eloquent 
{
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Subscription');
    }
}
```

Here is my subscription model

```php
class Subscription extends Eloquent 
{
    public function businesses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Business');
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that calling `dd` will stop your script, right?

Comment: I am if you replace the dd($subscription); with dd($subscription->type); Nothing is returned.

Comment: Ok, then how did you define the relationship between *business* and *subscription*?

Comment: I have added those to the original question. I have found a solution but I'm not sure its correct you can do $subscription->attributes['type'] to get the type but that seems silly.

Comment: Just a silly question, what happen if you do `Business::with('subscriptions')->get()[0]->check_for_subscription('test')`?

Comment: are the foreign keys correctly named so that the relation can be made?

Comment: He can access the attribute trough the attributes property so something is going wrong with __get()/getAttribute(). Hard to tell what, can't reproduce the problem. That's all in those models?

Comment: Should the Subscription not have belongsToMany('Business') instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the dd() output the Subscription object has no attribute named "type". That explains why you get nothing from $subscription->type.

According to the dd() output again, the Subscription object do has a protected attribute named "attributes", which is an array. One of the keys of that array is "type" so I'll assume that is the value you are trying to reach.

As the "attributes" array is protected you can't access it from an external class. I assume your Subscription class has a getter function named getAttributes() which returns that protected array. If so... the only thing you need is something like:

```
public function check_for_subscription($type)
{
    if($this->subscriptions->isEmpty() === false)
    {
        foreach($this->subscriptions as $subscription)
        {
            $attributes = $this->subscriptions->getAttributes();
            if($attributes['type'] == $type)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```